# I (a beginner) feel underscore is confusing

Tags: scala

I'm trying to learn programming with Scala, and I met some problem about the underscore.Here is the code:

```
FileMatcher.filesContaining("hello").foreach(println(_))

FileMatcher.filesContaining("hello").foreach(println((_:java.io.File).getName))
```

My question is, if underscore represent the formal parameter of a function(right?, i have seen some answer about underscore), why the first code runs well, but the second crashed?

=====================================================================

the whole code(sorry for my poor english. "crashed" means compile failed)

```
object FileMatcher{

  private def filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles

  def filesMatching(query: String, matcher: (String, String) => Boolean) =
    for (file <- filesHere if matcher(file.getName, query))
      yield file

  def filesEnding(query: String) =
    filesMatching(query, _.endsWith(_))

  def filesContaining(query: String) =
    filesMatching(query, _.contains(_))

}

FileMatcher.filesContaining("hello").foreach(println(_))

FileMatcher.filesContaining("hello").foreach(println((_:java.io.File).getName))
```

Comment: What you mean 'crashed'? Can you explain more the errors you get? Also the question title should be changed to reflect the question more clearly.

Comment: @Kermit try to use proper grammar and use of spaces after comma's in order for users to not skip your question.

Comment: What is `FileMatcher`? Please include all the information to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val seq: Seq[java.io.File] = Seq(new java.io.File("hello"))
```

In here:

```
seq.foreach(println(_))
```

...the underscore replaces the argument of `println` with the argument of an anonymous function (the function that is passed to `foreach`). This is equal to

```
seq.foreach(f => println(f))
```

In fact you could even shorten this to:

```
seq.foreach(println)
```

Whereas in:

```
seq.foreach(println(_.getName))
```

...you would pass a function `x => x.getName` to `println`. This doesn't compile because now you are ignoring that `foreach` takes a function of arity 1. You could for example attempt to write:

```
seq.foreach(f => println(_.getName))
```

Then still Scala has no idea what the argument type of `x => x.getName` is (because there is no context from which it could infer that). So:

```
seq.foreach(f => println((x: java.io.File) => x.getName))
```

The output:

> ```
> <function1>
> ```

Ooops. That's not what you wanted. You are printing the string representation of a function (without applying the function). Obviously, you are also not doing anything with `f`. So you see, the inner function is one bubble too much.

**Correct is:**

```
seq.foreach(f => println(f.getName))
```

Scala doesn't allow you to shorten this to `seq.foreach(println(_.getName))` because there is something in the middle between `foreach` and `getName` and that is the `println` method.